# Why do certain parts not move with the bones when rigging?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify

So I'm a beginner who is stuck. When I move a bone, some parts of the mesh remain in the same old position, particularly those faces that I formed with a knife (e.g. eyebrows, lips)

I'm using the metarig, rigify add-on. I have done <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> auto weights after applying all transforms and selecting the object first, then the armatures.

And this is what happens: it simply stretches and does not move with the rest of the mesh.

[image]

I don't get to grasp what seems to be the problem.

Comment: Pleas share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there and remembering to add the link to the file so that someone can have a look.

Comment: Have you checked for duplicated vertices? (key *M > Merge By Distance*)